# MySQL Searching for ANY word rather than ALL the words

Tags: mysql, search

The following code works for searching, but it doesn't work if you enter too much text into the search box.

For instance, if you search the phrase 'text in English' you receive a number of results. However, if you search the phrase 'text in English Language' it delivers NO result, because the word 'language' isn't in the fields it is searching.

In other words, the query is searching for the phrase in the text, not just any part of it.

I'm using this query:

```
$sqlcommand = "SELECT id,page_title,url,search_description,text1,text2,text3 
             FROM pages 
             WHERE concat(text1, ':', text2, ':', text3) LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
```

I'm looking for some advice, but I'm guessing the `LIKE '%$searchquery%'` part is the problem.

Cheers

Richard

Comment: It sounds like you really want full text search, probably with the boolean option.  Check out the documentation for more information (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what is being searched in and what is being searched for. "Search which searches for any word in the search" is maddeningly opaque. It doesn't work if you "enter too much text" - enter text where? In your database fields or your `$searchquery` string?

Comment: Question edited, hope it helps clear up what I'm asking.  Richard

Comment: Can you provide relevant sample data, search string and desired output  of the query? If you search as you stated by *...any part of...* query string you may grab all rows from your table with word like `in` or/and `text`...

Answer (score 2):

First of all **you really want a full text search for this**.

If you for some reason want to try to do it with pure SQL then

- first thing you need to do is to split you search string into words
- and filter out common words (pronouns, conjunctions, prepositions, etc) using some sort of stop list or/and filter out any words less then 2 or 3 characters long.

Something like this might do it for starters:

```php
$search_string = 'text in English Language';
$stop_list = array('in', 'on', 'I', 'me', 'he', 'she');
$search_words = explode(' ', $search_string);
$keywords = array_diff($search_words, $stop_list);
```

You'll get in `$keywords`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "text"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "English"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Language"
}
```

Now having a keywords array you can build a query like this

```sql
SELECT id, page_title, url, search_description, text1, text2, text3,
       (text LIKE '%text%') +
       (text LIKE '%English%') +
       (text LIKE '%language%') rank
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, page_title, url, search_description, text1, text2, text3,
         CONCAT_WS(' ', text1, text2, text3) text
    FROM pages p
) q
 WHERE text LIKE '%text%'   
    OR text LIKE '%English%'
    OR text LIKE '%language%'
HAVING rank > 1 -- play with cut-off rank value to get most relevant results
 ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Sample output:

```
+------+------------+------+--------------------+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+------+
| id   | page_title | url  | search_description | text1 | text2      | text3           | text                            | rank |
+------+------------+------+--------------------+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+------+
|    3 | page3      | url3 | NULL               | text  | English    | language        | text English language           |    3 |
|    1 | page1      | url1 | NULL               | text  | in English | text in English | text in English text in English |    2 |
+------+------------+------+--------------------+-------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+------+
```

***Note:** this query will be way slow and way less functional than any FTS solution.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/669c60/6)** demo

Comment: @Richard_Bedford Was it helpful?