# MYSQL Select LIKE and matching with spaces

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

I have a quick question. How do you get a MYSQL SELECT statement to work with the first word of a string entry.

For example I have this in my database

**Delivery to ROCKET FAO Paul Load**

I want to be able to search for any words in that and get a result. EG **Delivery**, **FAO Paul**, or **Load** etc etc.

However it never works when searching Delivery. I have used the follwoing Like expressions:

```
LIKE '%$param%'
LIKE '$param%'
LIKE '% $param %'
LIKE '$param'
REGEXP '$param'
REGEXP '%$param%'
```

But with no luck. The other search terms work just not searching for Delivery, This happens on all my data entrys where it wont find it if you search the on the word that appears first.

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT ... WHERE ... LIKE 'Delivery%'` work? Note also that to refer to the beginning of a line you use `^`, not `$` (end of line).

Comment: No :s, that was my first thought

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^Delivery'`.

Comment: Still nothing, debating whether its do to something else in my programme

Comment: It's something else.. `%` matches zero or more characters, so should be fine for the beginning of the string `LIKE '%$param%'`. Are you sure you spelt 'delivery' correctly? And that you aren't adding any white space to the string by accident.

Comment: Ok I found the problem, for some reason my computer/software/keyboard puts in a funny percentage symbol that isnt being recognised. Never came across that one before.

Comment: @snookian, see the answer as an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542233/mysql-searching-for-any-word-rather-than-all-the-words

Comment: If the reason was some typo, I suggest you should remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

This statement matches any word starting with Delivery

```
WHERE [columnNameHere] LIKE 'Delivery%'
```

Maybe you're talking about this

```
WHERE [columnNameHere] LIKE concat(@param, '%')
```